# jQuery How to count how many textareas have value? (not empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Lets think I have 10 textareas like this one:

```
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
```

The user write some of them and I want to check if they are more than 3, this is my attempt:

```
if($('textarea[value!=""]').length > 3) $('.result').val('more than 3');
else  $('.result').val('less than 3');
```

This doesn't work because textareas don't work with "value" attribute, so, how is the correct way to count them?

P.S.: I want to avoid making a .each(), check their values and accumulate them in a counter variable.

--- Edited ---

Snippets are giving me an errors, so I made a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaNRbV

---

```js
$('textarea').change(function(){
    if($('textarea[value!=""]').length > 3) $('.result').val('more than 3');
    else  $('.result').val('less than 3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<div>
Result: <input class="result" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you to use filter from jquery, so you can do something like this:

```
$("textarea").filter(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).length;
```

Here an example:

```js
$(function(){
  console.log("More than 3 => " + $("textarea").filter(function(){ return $(this).val().length >= 3 }).length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="seek[]">Example text</textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]">Example text</textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]">Example text</textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]">Example text</textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]">Example text</textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="seek[]"></textarea>
```

Comment: Wonderful, I didn't know the filter function, works like a charm